# Extract p values and estimates from blmer (list of regression models)?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I have a list of regression models that I created using `blmer` but I am unable to pull out the p-values as they are not in the `anova(model)` or using `summary(model)$coefficients` as I need to pull the p-values for multiple coefficients. Only when it is an `lmer` model that I have the p-value column available to extract. Is there a separate function or mean to calculate p-values from these regression models from `blmer`?

Here is an example, except I have a list of models:

```
m1 = blme::blmer(Y ~ sex + age + (1|id/Group), data=df) 
summary(m1)$coefficients 
anova(m1)
```

My output does not display a p-value column just t-values which I know is what the lmer models display but when you use `summary(model)` function on `lmer` you have a p-value column that is not displayed for `blmer`.

If I directly format my blmer models as output tables with `tab_model` for example then I have p-values but at this point it is an html table, is there a way for me to retrieve p-values at the regression coefficient model level for these models?

Comment: this might be better for CrossValidated; p-values are provided by lmerTest, via satterthwaite and kenward-roger approximations.  It's not obvious that these are applicable to regularized model fits via blmer ...

Comment: Thank you, but because my question regards the coding not the stats (CrossValidated does not allow it) as I know I can retrieve the p-values but I would like to do it when I have the regression models and not after I have formatted them into a table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sjPlot::tab_model` calls machinery from the `sjstat` package, which in turn calls machinery from the `parameters` package (the `p_value` function):

```
library(blme)
data("sleepstudy", package = "lme4")
fm1 <- blmer(Reaction ~ Days + (0 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
               cov.prior = gamma)
parameters::p_value(fm1)
##    Parameter            p
##1 (Intercept) 0.000000e+00
##2        Days 8.228424e-08
```

However: from a statistical point of view I would advise being **VERY** cautious with these p-values. The help page for `?parameters:p_value` says

> This function attempts to return, or compute, p-values of a
>        model's parameters. The nature of the p-values is different
>        depending on the model:
>           • Mixed models (lme4): TO BE IMPROVED.

and below that it indicates that it returns Wald p-values by default. These p-values do **not** account for:

- non-quadratic nature of the log-likelihood surface (for which we need likelihood profile CIs)
- finite-size corrections (for which we need Satterthwaite/Kenward-Roger/"inner-outer" degrees-of-freedom approximations)
- the effect of the Bayesian priors (whose effect on frequentist p-values hasn't really been studied by anyone to my knowledge, because the question is a mish-mash of Bayesian and frequentist approaches)

Comment: Thank you for the information this is exactly what I wanted to know, I'm purely working out these packages so just experimenting with their functions. I appreciate the additional info very much though!

Comment: Some packages (in particular **sjstats**) currently receive major revisions. most of the sjstats functions are now re-implemented in more dedicated packages from the [easystats-projetcs](https://github.com/easystats). As Ben mentioned, the `p_value()` function is now located in the **parameters** package. You can get at least bootstrapped CIs using `ci(fm1, method = "boot")`. @Ben-Bolker, we are happy for any suggestions how to "improve" p-values (i.e. get more accurate p-values), so please let us know.